# Time-dependent GUROBI optimization: extract variables as dictionaries/lists/tuples

Tags: python, gurobi

I am working with a time-dependent optimization problem. I have two sets: `U = {usr1, ..., usr4}` and `T = {0,1,...,23}`.

I have different sets of variables and constraints, some variables are set upon the set U, some others upon the set T, and the majority on both. When I retrieve the variables values with `m.getVars()` it looks like this:

```
a[usr1] = 123        
    ... 
a[usr4] = 987
b[0] = 12 
b[1] = 34 
... 
b[23] = 89
c[usr1,0] = 1
c[usr1,1] = 2
...
c[usr1,23] = 1
c[usr2,0] = 2
...
c[usr4,22] = 3
c[usr4,23] = 4
```

Is there an efficient way to create a dictionary to handle easier the results?

What I am looking for is something like this:

```
a = {usr1 : 123,
     usr2 : 456,
     usr3 : 789,
     usr4 : 987}

b = {0 : 12,
     1 : 34,
     ...
     23 : 89}

c = {usr1 : {0 : 1,
             1 : 2,
             ...}
     ...
     usr4 : { ...
             22 : 3
             23 : 4}}
```

Thanks for the help.

EDIT:

I have tried this:

```
sols = {}
for var in m.getVars():
    name = var.VarName.split('[')[0]
    arg =var.VarName.split('[')[1].split(']')[0]
    sols[name] = {arg : var.X}
```

but it does not work: the `sols` dictionary has only the last element of the variables, in this case:

```
sols = {'a' : {'usr4' : 987}
        'b' : {'23' : 89}
        'c' : {'usr4,23' : 4}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think it would be easier to create a [gurobi tupledict](http://www.gurobi.com/documentation/8.0/quickstart_windows/py_the_tupledict_class.html) for each of your variables. In this case you don't need to extract the variable names and indices. Instead you can iterate over your two sets directly via a *dict comprehension*:

```
from gurobipy import *

U = {"usr1", "usr2", "usr3", "usr4"}
T = set(i for i in range(24))

m = Model()
a = m.addVars(U, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="a")
b = m.addVars(T, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="b")
c = m.addVars(U, T, vtype=GRB.INTEGER, name="c")

m.update()
# Your constraints and objective here
# m.optimize()

# Now creating the dictionaries:
dic_a = {usr: a[usr].X for usr in U}
dic_b = {i: b[i].X for i in T}
dic_c = {usr : {i : c[usr, i].X for i in T} for usr in U}
```

Note that it's a nested dict comprehension for `dic_c`.